# SharedPreferences - исчезают данные или не находит, почему?

Tags: android

В приложение в одном активити вызываю диалог, где задаю вопрос, исходя из ответа вношу данные в SharedPreferences. После это го делаю сразу проверку, внеслись данные или нет, показывает что внеслись.

```
//Метод показа диалога пункта "Аутенфикации"
private void showAutenficationDialog() {
    final SharedPreferences.Editor[] editor = {sPreferences.edit()};
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "MainActivity - showAutenficationDialog - Метод показа диалога пункта \"Аутенфикации\"");
    //Создаем билдер
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //Устанавливаем Заголовок
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_autenfocation_titlle);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_autenfocation_text);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_autenfocation_btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //объект для редактирования настроек
            editor[0].putString(Constants.AUTENT_ACTIVITY, "Да");
            editor[0].commit();
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "MainActivity - showAutenficationDialog - Метод показа диалога пункта \"Аутенфикации\" - Выбрали Да");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toast_enter_pass_on, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //проверяем что сейчас в настройках, получилось внести или нет
            sPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            //Если в настройках указано false - не проверяем пароль, открываем Main
            String flagProverka = sPreferences.getString(Constants.AUTENT_ACTIVITY, "---");
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, " в настройках указано - " + flagProverka);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_autenfocation_btn_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //объект для редактирования настроек
            editor[0].putString(Constants.AUTENT_ACTIVITY, "Нет");
            editor[0].commit();
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "MainActivity - showAutenficationDialog - Метод показа диалога пункта \"Аутенфикации\" - Выбрали Нет");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toast_enter_pass_off, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            sPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            //Если в настройках указано false - не проверяем пароль, открываем Main
            String flagProverka = sPreferences.getString(Constants.AUTENT_ACTIVITY, "---");
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, " в настройках указано - " + flagProverka);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

В другом активити, мне нужно залезть в в эти данные:

```
SharedPreferences sPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
//Если в настройках указано false - не проверяем пароль, открываем Main
String flagProverka = sPreferences.getString(Constants.AUTENT_ACTIVITY, "---");
Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, " в настройках указано - " + flagProverka);
```

Но получаю значение по умолчанию "---". Почему так, почему проверка сразу находит данные, а в другом активити нет. Ощущение что я не туда записываю.

Comment: Попробуйте получать глобальные преференсы так: `PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`

Comment: И уточните на каком языке пишете - что-то не совсем на яву похоже. Например вот это совсем не понятно что такое: `SharedPreferences.Editor[] editor = {sPreferences.edit()};`

Comment: И зачем вам тут массив: `final SharedPreferences.Editor[] editor = {sPreferences.edit()};` ? Если изменить на `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPreferences.edit();` и `editor.putString();`, ошибки больше нет?

Comment: Перед использованием того или иного метода советую прочитать по нему документацию.

Comment: Это 'SharedPreferences.Editor[] editor = {sPreferences.edit()};'  хочет Андроид студия при диалоге, принципиально ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 3):

Короче, сам разобрался, если использовать

```
sPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Создается файл, с именем пакет + название Активити, то есть для каждого Активити свой файл настроек, если надо чтоб настройки были общими для всего приложения, нужно указывать имя файла таким образом:

```
sPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Тогда настройки видны всем активити.